# Запомнить положение скролла при смене компонента

Tags: javascript, angular2

Помогите пожалуйста запомнить положение скролла при смене отображения компонента.

Есть список статей, он состоит из тизеров статей. При клике на тизер открывается страничка с полным текстом статьи.я Хотел бы на страничке со списком статей прокрутить экран вниз и нажать на одну из статей. Откроется старница с полным текстом статьи. Затем я хотел бы нажать кнопку Назад и вернуться к списку статей. Но чтобы скролл был в прокрученном положении

Всё это я реализовал, кроме запоминания положения скролла.

У меня есть компонент articles. В его шаблоне по *ngIf выводятся компоненты: articles-list, articles-details. если первый виден, то второй не виден. И наоборот. Выглядит шаблон компонета articles приблизительно так:

```
<app-articles-list  *ngIf="!showArticleDetails" 
                                        (onClickArticleTeaser)="handlerClickArticleTeaser($event)" 
                                        id="articlesList"></app-articles-list>

<app-article-details    *ngIf="showArticleDetails" 
                                            (onClickBackBtn)="setVisibilityDetailsPage(false)" 
                                            [articleObj]="articleObj"></app-article-details>
```

В компоненте articles-list при клике по тизеру статьи вычисляется значение положения скролла:

```
  private getScrollTop(id) {
    let el = document.getElementById(id);
    let scrollTop = el.scrollTop;

    console.log(id, '--', el, '--', scrollTop);

    return scrollTop;
  };
```

Мне не понятно куда его сохранять чтобы пользователь, вернувшись со страницы полного текста статьи к странице со списком тизеров статей, увидел, что компонент articles-list применил сохранённое ранее значение скролла и прокрутил список до нужного места.

Мне нужен ответ словами. Что куда передавать и как сохранять

Comment: Можете сделать сервис для этого скрола. Он будет хранить состояние между переходами.

Comment: Я могу и в локалсторадже хранить значение. Но это всё идеологически не правильные решения

Comment: А что по вашему идеологически правильное? Где хранить? В observable в сервисе для конкретного компонента довольно правильный вариант если нужен при переходах. В локалсторедже, если нужно хранить между посещениями сайта. Больше никак. В компоненте самом нельзя, так как после перехода он очиститься.